# Fix a PHP error - Notice Undefined index: url

Tags: php, plugins

I'm getting Warning: Use of undefined constant 'url' - assumed "url" for lines 6 and 7 below from the main.php for the plugin mp3j-player (Query monitor finds a further 480 errors I think based from these two?). I am an absolute PHP novice, but have been trying out various codes from reading similar issues that others have questioned. This has resulted in either nothing or breaking the plugin. As I understand it it is just a notice for now but may break with future versions of PHP so if possible I am trying to fix it.

```
function removeRemoteTracks ( $playlist )
{
    $filtered = array();
    foreach ( $playlist as $track )
    {   
        if ( strpos($track['url'], $this->Rooturl) !== false 
            || ( strpos($track['url'], 'http://') === false && strpos($track['url'], 'https://') === false )
            || ( strpos($this->theSettings['mp3_dir'], "http://") !== false && strpos($track['url'], $this->theSettings['mp3_dir']) !== false ) )
        {
            $filtered[] = $track;           
        }
    }
    return $filtered;
}
```

Cheers

Edit:
So....after much trial and error and following Tigran's suggestions I have found that changing 'url' to 'src' has removed the PHP Notice. I also tried 'filename' which worked. I found these in the same main.php file as above and I suppose they would all work? Everything still seems to work how I am using the plugin. But... is this a bodge? Might I be better "defining" 'url' in the list below?

```
//###############
function newTrack ()
{
    return array(
        'src'           => '',
        'filename'      => '',
        'formats'       => array(),
        'counterpart'   => '',
        'title'         => '',
        'caption'       => '',
        'image'         => '',
        'link'          => ''
    );
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means that some of your tracks does not have URL index. Debug them with var_dump.

```
function removeRemoteTracks($playlist) {
    $filtered = [];

    foreach ($playlist as $track) {   
        // Debug
        if (!isset($track['url'])) {
            var_dump($track); // Look what's wrong with tracks without URL
        }

        if (strpos($track['url'], $this->Rooturl) !== false 
            || (strpos($track['url'], 'http://') === false && strpos($track['url'], 'https://') === false)
            || (strpos($this->theSettings['mp3_dir'], "http://") !== false && strpos($track['url'], $this->theSettings['mp3_dir']) !== false )) {
            $filtered[] = $track;           
        }
    }

    return $filtered;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tigran. I tried replacing the original code with what you suggest. Is that right? I broke the plugin so maybe that's not what I should be doing.

Comment: Of course it will. It is for you to debug $track. Some of $track does not have **url** index.

Comment: Got you. Where can I find the output? Thanks.

Comment: Most probably at the top of website or there where you use those tracks. If it is from database just check if they all have URL

Comment: Still stumped. I've checked every track. They all have an url or short code and all play. I've screenshot what happened when I put the code in which may (or may not) help https://photos.app.goo.gl/tGYRuLkQCRcB72PD8 - the players still loaded and tracks played.

Comment: Well, the error says us that there is an element in $playlist that does not have url index when you try to access it.